# How to subtract date only format "mm/dd" in excel?

Tags: date, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010, subtraction

My date data was pulled from our system with the format "mm/dd" not the year.

So I meet the problem when I subtract value between the old year and the current year.

Example:
Date action         Date Check          Result        Current Date
12/21               01/03               -352          03/18/2022

The correct result is:
Date action         Date Check          Result        Current Date
12/21               01/03               13            03/18/2022

How to subtract correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Excel has treated `12/21` and `01/03` as dates, but in doing this has assumed the current year in all cases. This dedcuts 1 year from cell A2

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2)-1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))
```

e.g.
Test if the earlier date has a month less than the latter date, if it is not then deduct 1 year from the earlier date and then calculate the difference

```
  +------------+------------+------+
  |      A     |     B      |   C  |
1 |   earlier  |   latter   | diff |
  +------------+------------+------+
2 | 2022-12-21 | 2022-01-03 |   13 |
  +------------+------------+------+

in cell C2

=IF(MONTH(A2) > MONTH(B2),B2-DATE(YEAR(A2)-1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),B2-A2)
```